# Props is empty in view but not in REDUX STATE

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have some problem with my REACT-REDUX. I just fallow this guide: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript.

Redux just updates its state when I call Thunk Action from view to confirm that I just check a REDUX dev tool to check a current state. Problem is that I take a prop from Redux and I want to render all of element in ToDos array, REDUX devtools show me that there is a 2-3 elements inside that array but prop  in view is empty. Any sugestions ? Check images below.

[Image of props state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orLtF.png)
[Image of AppState from Redux Dev Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX2Fk.png)

Reducer :

```
export interface ToDoState {
    toDos : ToDoElement[],
    errors : String[]
}

const InitialState: ToDoState = {
    toDos : [],
    errors: []
}


export function  toDoReducer(state = InitialState,action: ToDoActionTypes) : ToDoState{
    switch(action.type){
        case ToDoActions.ADD_TODO:
            state.toDos = [action.todo,...state.toDos]
        return state;
        case ToDoActions.FETCH_REQUEST:
            return state;
        case ToDoActions.FETCH_SUCCESS:
        state.toDos = action.todos;
            return state;
        case ToDoActions.FETCH_ERROR:
            return state;
        case ToDoActions.REMOVE_TODO:
        state.toDos.filter(x=>x !== action.todo);
            return state
        case ToDoActions.RENAME_TODO:
      state.toDos = state.toDos.map((item) => {
            if(item.id === action.todo.id) {
                action.todo.tittle = action.newName;
              return item;
            }

            return item;
          });
        return state

         default :
            return state;

    }
}
```

View Redux connect  and componnent call thunk action

```
     componentDidMount() {
            this.props.startFetchToDos();
        }

        render(){
            const items = this.props.toDoState.toDos.map((item,i)=>
            <SingleToDo todo={item} key={i} > </SingleToDo>
       );
```

```
interface LinkStateProp{
    toDos : ToDoElement[]
    toDoState:ToDoState
}
interface LinkDispatchProps{
    startFetchToDos: () =>void;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state:AppState) : LinkStateProp =>({
  toDos : state.toDo.toDos,
  toDoState:state.toDo
});


const mapeDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any,any,AppActions>)  :  LinkDispatchProps =>({
    startFetchToDos: bindActionCreators(fetchToDos,dispatch)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapeDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Store

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    toDo:toDoReducer
});

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

export default function configureStore() {
  const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware];
  const middleWareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeEnhancers(middleWareEnhancer)
  );

  return store;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell from so much code. The first thing I would do is returning new state from reducers instead of reassigning it's properties. Check the documentation you linked to see how to do it.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin That was a issue. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about the fact that you are mutating your redux state inside your reducer. Never mutate your redux state. Instead use immutable update patterns.

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

I have updated your reducer cases about the issue. You should be able to change others.

```
export function  toDoReducer(state = InitialState,action: ToDoActionTypes) : ToDoState{
    switch(action.type){
        case ToDoActions.ADD_TODO:
            // state.toDos = [action.todo,...state.toDos]
            return { ...state, toDos: [ ...state.toDos, action.todo ] }
        case ToDoActions.FETCH_REQUEST:
            return state;
        case ToDoActions.FETCH_SUCCESS:
            // state.toDos = action.todos;
            return { ...state, toDos: [ ...action.todos ] }
        case ToDoActions.FETCH_ERROR:
            return state;
         default :
            return state;

    }
}
```

The fact is that, your connected components are comparing current state and next state. But since both reference the same object, no rerender happens.

Comment: That was a issue. Thanks for help !